# $L(\bigoplus_{i\in I} H_i)\cong \prod_{i\in I}L(H_i)$ as Banach spaces?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, universal-property

Let $\{H_i:i\in I\}$ be a system of complex Hilbert spaces, $L(\bigoplus_{i\in I} H_i)$ the set of bounded linear maps $T:\bigoplus_{i\in I} H_i\to \bigoplus_{i\in I} H_i$, equipped with the operator norm. 
Let $\prod_{i\in I}L(H_i)$ the direct product of linear maps endowed with the norm $\|(T_i)_{i\in I}\|=sup_{i\in I}\|T_i\|$.

Is $$L(\bigoplus_{i\in I} H_i)\cong \prod_{i\in I}L(H_i)$$ as banach spaces?
The map which comes to my mind constructed as follows: Is $$\iota_i: H_i\to \bigoplus_{i\in I} H_i$$ the canonical injection, we define for each $i\in I$ a map $$\varphi_i:L(\bigoplus_{i\in I} H_i)\to L(H_i),\; \alpha\mapsto \alpha\circ \iota_i$$ Then extend it to a map $$L(\bigoplus_{i\in I} H_i)\to \prod_{i\in I}L(H_i).$$ But I'm not sure if it's possible here or if the construction makes sense in this context.

Comment: Did you consider the case $I=\lbrace 1,2\rbrace$ and $H_i=\mathbb C$? You then get *matrices*.

Comment: then I get the same, if I have done everything correctly. But I needed that $I$ is finite, therefore I suppose that the claim is only true if $I$ is finite.

Comment: For $H_i=\mathbb C$ you get $L(H_i)\cong \mathbb C$. Then $\prod_{i\in \lbrace 1,2\rbrace} L(H_i)\cong \mathbb C^2$  but $L(\bigoplus_i H_i)\cong \mathbb C^{2\times 2}\cong \mathbb C^4$ .

Comment: oh, okay, then I did a mistake and the satement is wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that isomorphically there is only one Hilbert space in each dimension. Moreover, $$d( \bigoplus_{i\in I} H_i)=\sum_{i\in I}  d(H_i),$$
where $d$ stands for the dimension, that is, cardinality of any orthonormal basis. Thus if all $H_i$ have the same dimension $\lambda$ say, then $d(\bigoplus_{i\in I} H_i) = \max\{\lambda, |I|\}$. Presumably, by $\prod_{i\in I} E_i$ you mean the $\ell_\infty(I)$-direct sum of $E_i$ ($i\in I$).

In general then the answer is **no**.

Indeed, if each $H_i$ is two-dimensional and $I$ is infinite, then $(\bigoplus_{i\in I} L(H_i))_{\ell_\infty(I)}$ is Banach-space isomorphic to $\ell_\infty(I)$ but $L( (\bigoplus_{i\in I}H_i)_{\ell_2(I)})$ is the space of operators on an infinite dimensional Hilbert space $H$ which is known to be not isomorphic to $\ell_\infty(I)$ for any infinite index set $X$. To see this, note that $L(H)$ contains a complemented subspace isomorphic to $\ell_2$. Pick a non-zero vector $x\in H$ and consider

$$H^\prime=\{x\otimes y\colon\quad y\in H\}.$$

Then $H^\prime$ is complemented and $H\cong H^\prime$. As $\ell_\infty$ has the [Dunford–Pettis property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunford%E2%80%93Pettis_property), it contains no infinite-dimensional, complemented reflexive subspaces.

In some cases the answer is **yes**. For example, it is an unpublished result of Lindenstrauss and Haagerup which says that

$$L(\ell_2)\quad \text{and }\quad(\bigoplus_{n\in \mathbb{N}} L(\ell_2^n))_{\ell_\infty}$$

are isomorphic as Banach spaces. The proof is highly non-constructive and uses the Pełczyński decomposition method. It is explained in

> E. Christensen and A. Sinclair, [Completely bounded isomorphisms of injective von Neumann algebras](http://journals.cambridge.org/download.php?file=%2FPEM%2FPEM2_32_02%2FS0013091500028716a.pdf&code=3a0f9c7fec648eae559d97c60a9e146d), *Proc. Edingurgh Math. Soc.* **32** (1989), 317–327.

Comment: thank you for the great helpful answer!